# Sorting list in Python (another way)

Tags: python, arrays

So here is the problem:

Input an array of positive integers and need to return sum of all elements in new array with conditions: if `Array[i] > Array[j]` then `Array[i] = Array[i] - Array[j]`.
Example:

```
[1,2,3] => [1,2,1] => [1,1,1] => output: 3
```

My code:

```
def solution(a):
    while max(a) != min(a):
        u = max(a)
        a[a.index(u)] = u - min(a) 
    return (a[0] * len(a))
```

But this code is very slow, how can I refactor it for better performance ?

Comment: Are you looking to do this manually? In other words, you don't want to use `sorted`? Because it is a bit *funny* that you are using `max` and `min`, but not `sorted`.

Comment: `min`, `max` and `index` are `O(n)`, this is what makes the code slow.

Comment: How can I sort this array with such conditions?

Comment: this code outputs one integer value, not a list. you'll need to explain your problem more clearly. give an example of expected input/output

Comment: You aren't sorting anything here, you're just applying this formula, that's all.

Comment: @ForceBru. You took the words right out of my mouth. The description does not match the code very well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you mean, it doesn't match it _at all_.

Comment: what should it return id the condition is not met?

Comment: use sort or sorted man

Comment: If you're trying to sort without builtins, I would recommend you read up on [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), [heap sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) or [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: @ForceBru. I've already voted as unclear: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256328/2988730

Comment: @binu.py. What does sorted have anything to do with this?

Comment: So, this is definitely _not_ sorting. Please update the title and explain what `Array[i]` and `Array[j]` are supposed to be and where you get these indices. If they're the `min` and `max`, you probably have no other options. What you _can_ do, though, is to calculate `max` and `min` only once per iteration.

Comment: Your code goes `[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 2, 2] -> [1, 1, 2] -> [1, 1, 1]`

Comment: @Jared Goguen, i think algorithm in post faster than algorithm in code. Sorry I bad in English

Comment: @ForceBru indices i and j are random

Comment: your condition and example don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you implemented roughly applies the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to a group of numbers. The following code is equivalent to yours, but more efficient:

```
from fractions import gcd

a = [1, 2, 3]
print reduce(gcd, a) * len(a) # 3
```

Whether or not your code does what you want it to do is another story. In Python 3.X, `reduce` will have to be imported from `functools`.

Comment: Thank you. How many tools in Python I don`t know. Your code work perfectly